# Debugger lines not matching up in VS2015

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Not entirely sure what's going on here. I'm trying to debug some lines and when jumping through the code, it appears that certain lines are skipped and even the visual doesn't line up with what's currently being debugged.

This is an ASP.NET Core project. I'm running the debug configuration. Has anyone else seen this?

[image: Debugger Issue]

Comment: How did you debug your app, using Step Into(F11) or others? If you comment out certain line code, does it impact your app's running? During debugging, please also enable the Exception settings under Debug->Windows-> Exception Settings, maybe it has certain unhand exception in your project.

Comment: It hit that breakpoint below actually in the example in the picture. I ended up solving it by putting each line of code (124 & 127) on one line instead of breaking it up. I don't think this is really an answer but it works

Comment: Generally if we just put two line code together(one line), it would hit this line code two time if you debug your app using F11.  If it just hit it for one time, maybe it still has this issue even if it was the result you want to get. Just add output messages code like Debug.Print("xxx") between line 125 and 127, and then debug it again using F11, what is the result?